# Pre-Build Output file to Release project directory C#

Tags: c#

I'm new on pre-build and have a external file to copy:

G:\temp\andre\InstaladorCertificados.zip

And i need to put this .zip file in \bin\Release in my project in Pre-Build event command line.

I'm trying that script: xcopy "$G:\temp\andre\InstaladorCertificados.zip" "$(OutDir)"
And i get that error: The command "xcopy "$G:\temp\andre\InstaladorCertificados.zip" "$(OutDir)"" exited with code 4.

Is there a way to copy a external file to my project in pre-build event ?

Comment: You don't need the `$G:\` since  it's not a macro. You need simply `G:\`

Comment: Hello! I tried and error persist. I could make "work" using: Copy "$(InputFileName)G:\temp\andre\InstaladorCertificados.zip" "$(OutDir)", but he's creating two bin files and two release files in compilation time

Comment: What do you mean by creating 2 bin files and 2 release files? You mean 2 bin `folders`?

Comment: Hello! Yeah, using (OutPut) in this script, i have bin\Release\bin\Release\InstaladorCertificados.zip

Comment: What's the purpose of `$(InputFileName)` in front of `G:\temp` Do you need it? Shouldn't just be copy "G:\temp\andre\InstaladorCertificados.zip" "$(OutDir)" ?`

Comment: Removing $(InputFileName) i get error: The command "copy "G:\temp\andre\InstaladorCertificados.zip" "$(OutDir)"" exited with code 4.